# How to make a docker compose service to use multiple network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

everyone, I have a requirement to write a docker-compose.yml which need to make one of service to use two network, one for the default for communication with each other service and one for the external bridge network for auto self discovery via nginx-proxy.

My docker-compose.yml like the belows.

```
version: '2'
services:
  dns-management-frontend:
    image: ......
    depends_on:
    - dns-management-backend
    ports:
    - 80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
      - bridge
  dns-management-backend:
    image:......
    depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
  db:
    image: ......
    volumes:
    - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - 6379
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
  bridge:
    external:
      name: bridge
    networks:
      - default
```

When I start with it, it gave me `network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks` error. I have to remove the networks section in services, and after started, manually ran `docker network connect <id_of_frontend_container> bridge` to make it work.

Any advice on how to configure multiple network in docker-compose? I also have read https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/, but it is too simple.

Comment: ``networks:`` is a top-level key, there is another nested key ``networks`` in this docker composer.

Answer (score 1):

The Docker network named `bridge` [is special](https://docs.docker.com/network/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge); most notably, it doesn't provide DNS-based service discovery.

For your proxy service, you should `docker network create` some other network, named anything other than `bridge`, either `docker network connect` the existing container to it or restart the proxy `--net the_new_network_name`.  In the `docker-compose.yml` file change the `external: {name: ...}` to the new network name.

> Any advice on how to configure multiple network in docker-compose?

As you note Docker Compose (and for that matter Docker proper) doesn't support especially involved network topologies.  At the half-dozen-containers scale where Compose works well, you don't really need an involved network topology.  Use the `default` network that Docker Compose provides for you, and don't bother manually configuring `networks:` unless it's actually necessary (as the external proxy is in your question).

Comment: Thanks, I see, however I could not manually execute docker command like `docker network create ...` because I deployed my app in https://daocloud.io which it only support `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

you can not mixing for now the default bridge with other networks in `compose`

[issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3476) is still open ...